# Assign table to table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

In Lua, I can add an entry inside table with `table.insert(tableName, XYZ)`. Is there a way I can add already existing table into table? I mean a directly call rather then traversing and add it.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean adding an existing table by reference or by value? If by value that would imply copying the contents from the existing table to a new table and inserting that. The former does not require any traversal when adding since no copying is being done. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

The insert in your example will work fine with whatever contents happen to be inside the XYZ variable (number, string, table, function, etc.).

That will not copy the table though it will insert the actual table. If you want to insert a copy of the table then you need to traverse it and insert the contents.

Answer (score 3):

First: In general, you do *not* need table.insert to put new entries into tables.
A table in Lua is a collection of key-value pairs; entries can be made like this:

```
local t = {}  --the table
local key= "name"
local value = "Charlie"

t[key] = value  --make a new entry (replace an existing value at the same key!)
print(t.name) --> "Charlie"
```

Note that *key* can have *any* type (not just integer/string)!

Very often you will need tables for a simple special case of this: A sequence ("list", "array") of values. For Lua, this means you want a table where all the keys are consecutive integers, and contain all non-nil values. The table.insert function is intended for that special case: It allows you to insert a value at a certain position (or to append it at the end of the sequence if no position is specified):

```
local t = {"a", "b", "d"} --a sequence containing three strings (t[1] = "a", ...)

table.insert(t, "e") --append "e" to the sequence

table.insert(t, 3, "c") --insert "c" at index 3 (moving values at higher indices)

--print the whole sequence
for i=1,#t do
  print(t[i])
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you mean correctly, you want to do this:

```
local t1 = {1, 2, 3}
local t2 = {4, 5, 6}
some_function(t1, t2)
-- t1 is now {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

There is indeed no way to do this without iterating `t2`. Here is a way to write `some_function`:

```
local some_function = function(t1, t2)
  local n = #t1
  for i=1,#t2 do t1[n+i] = t2[i] end
end
```

Comment: What if the source-table is hierachy table? I dont know how much this hierarchy will go on

Answer (score 2):

No, you must copy the second table's key/value pairs into the first table. Copying the existing values from the second table is what's known as a "shallow copy." The first table will reference the same objects as the second table.

This works under limited circumstances:

```
local n = #t1
for i=1,#t2 do t1[n+i] = t2[i] end
```

It does attempt to shift the `t2` elements to just beyond the existing `t1` elements. That could be a vital requirement but wasn't stated in the question.

It has a few of problems, though:

- By using `#t1` and `#t2`, it misses keys that aren't positive integers and can miss keys that are integers greater than a skipped integer key (i.e. never assigned or assigned `nil`).
- It accesses the first table with an indexer so could invoke the `__newindex` metamethod. That *probably* wouldn't be desirable when only copying is wanted.
- It accesses the second table with an indexer so could invoke the `__index` metamethod. That wouldn't be desirable when only copying is wanted.

You might think that `ipairs` could be used if only positive integer keys are wanted but it quits on the first `nil` value found so could miss even more than `#t2` does.

Use `pairs` instead:

```
for key, value in pairs(t2) do 
    rawset( t1, key, value )
end
```

If you do want to avoid replacing existing `t1` values when the keys match or otherwise map `t2` keys in some way then that has to be defined in the requirements.

Bottom line: `pairs` is the way to get all the keys. It effectively does a `rawget` so it avoids invoking `__index`. `rawset` is the way to do a copy without invoking `__newindex`.

Comment: thanks Tom. What if the source-table is hierachy table (table inside table)? I dont know how many hierarchy-level will exist. will above will work in this?

Comment: Each key in a table holds a reference to a value. The value can be anything (except `nil`, in which case the key is deleted), including a table. So, when copying a value, it is the reference to the value that is copied. If the value refers to an inner table, the copy will refer to the same inner table. That's the same thing as you are doing with `table.insert`. If that's okay then you're done. If you want a "deep copy" rather than a "shallow copy", say so in the question and why. Also, see [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable).